# Shell_NotifyIcon not working even in Microsoft example

Tags: c#, c++, windows, winapi, notification-area

`Shell_NotifyIcon` does not show balloon tips for me. The icon shows up for a millisecond and disappears, and no text is shown. So, I downloaded Microsoft's [NotificationIcon](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/shell/appshellintegration/NotificationIcon) example from GitHub, and built it. Had to change Windows SDK in the project from 8.1 to 10.0.17763.0. The example runs, and the icon is shown in notification area, but again the actions that are supposed to show tooltips do not show them. The icon flashes into view for a millisecond, and that's it.

Then I tried [C# example from the Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.notifyicon), and just added `notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(3000, "Tip Title", "Tip text", ToolTipIcon.Info)` to a button Click handler. Same thing, icon appears briefly, and no balloon for me.

What's going on?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-do-i-disable-balloon-tips-in-the-notification-area-in-windows-xp-or-vista-fbc7583c-945a-aeb1-3c55-f3f0e005baef

Comment: With Windows 10, no balloon is shown, you'll get a new notification in the notification area. https://i1.wp.com/pcguide4u.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/notification-area-icon.jpg?ssl=1

Comment: Simon got it right. They moved balloons tips to toast notifications. Never payed attention to them before. Best UI decision ever... @Simon please make it an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Windows 10, balloons are not shown anymore (too intrusive). Instead, you'll get a new notification available in the notification area:

[image]